# Homework - Calculating normal force with additional accelerations (besides gravity)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

I'm working on a problem, and I'm getting too muddled in trying to figure what is the normal force.

[image: The problem]

If the whole thing was at rest, the normal force would simply be the angled reaction for $mg$, but since an acceleration is acting on the system, I'm thinking it will "relieve" some of the normal force (i.e. act against the horizontal $mg$ force to lessen the amount that the normal force has to accommodate for [if that makes sense?]). But I think I'm getting confused because I have an acceleration to work with, not a force.

I finally cracked and peeked in the back of the book. Using the value it gives for $O_y$, it seems that the normal force should be 438.357N. This is assuming that $\Sigma F_y = 0 = -mg + N cos\theta + O_y$.
But if I take the sum of the moments about O (which will eliminate $O_y$, $O_x$, and I'm thinking any force related to $a$?), I get that $2 mg cos \theta= N$, so then $N =$ 588.6N.

So I guess I'm officially confused... how does that normal force work with that acceleration at $O$?

Comment: the problem didn't say there is gravity..

Comment: Hmm, is this one of those options where static equilibrium removes the $mg$ factor? I hadn't thought of that, but I still don't know how to cope with the $a$ to the right.

Comment: perhaps treat it as if $a$ is $g$ (or $-g$)

Comment: This is not so difficult, think of 'a' acting like 'g' but in the -x- axis.So there's a 'weight, of ma in the horizontal direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an accelerating frame of reference which is moving along with the apparatus. Introduce pseudo-force $ma$ acting on the CM of the rod, horizontally to the left, where $m$ is the mass of the rod. The force of gravity $mg$ is still acting vertically in the accelerating frame.

The rod is in equilibrium under the forces in the accelerating frame. Balancing moments for the pseudo force, gravity and normal reaction about O should enable you to find the normal reaction from A.